# How would Undead Fortitude and Regeneration work in tandem?

Tags: dnd-5e, encounter-design, homebrew-review, monster-design

I've created a custom undead for a campaign I'm running called a *dread zombie*. The idea is for it to have a bit of a "you've got to be kidding me" factor with how resilient the seemingly weak enemy is. In addition to giving it way more health than a typical zombie, (and a slightly less pathetic AC), I've added the regeneration trait to the monster similar to the one on a troll, but with 1d12+1 hit points instead of a flat ten.

[image: Here it is]

Looking it over, most of what I made seems fine, but I'm not sure how having both *undead resiliance* and *regeneration* will work.

- Should the Dread Zombie immediately make the *undead resiliance* constitution save once its health goes to zero, or should it make the save only if it starts a round when it can't regenerate, since regeneration says that the creature only dies if that condition is met?
- Should I tweak the regeneration ability to make it weak to radiant damage instead of fire, in order to create more synergy between the two traits?

Comment: Would you happen to have a text version of this monster entry you could link us to as well?

Comment: Quick suggestion: instead of "1d8 necrotic damage *per turn*", it should probably state something along the lines of "1d8 necrotic damage *at the start of its turn*". That way the condition is less ambiguous and more consistent with the style of other abilities.

Comment: Making an annoying "bag o' hit points" monster like this is good for a "once in a while" encounter. If you make it a habit, your players' fun will get overwritten by frustration.  As with any spice or seasoning on your dinner: just enough to change the flavor, not so much as to ruin the flavor.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Awesome analogy: time for a snack! ;)

Answer (score 8):

### The Dread Zombie should make the *Undead Fortitude* save each time that it drops to zero hit points.

Like the Troll, this means that the Dread Zombie will have the Incapacitated condition in the time between being reduced to zero hit points and regenerating health via *Regeneration*.

Essentially, the Dread Zombie uses its *Undead Fortitude* feature to stave off becoming Incapacitated, and uses *Regeneration* to stave off death itself.

All in all, a very neat monster concept.